# MEncoder AC3 has no sound when run with VLC

Tags: vlc, mencoder, ac3

Encoding video with MEncoder (MEncoder SVN R34540 (Ubuntu)) with AC3 codec from lavc, results in no sound on VLC 2.03.
The encoded video sounds OK on Totem or Mplayer but there is no sound on VLC.

VLC plays AC3 sound from original video, but when I use `-oac` copy option with MEncoder the result is the same.

My OS: Ubuntu 12.04 x64

Comment: Perhaps you could try using the latest version, instead. You can download it [here](http://www.videolan.org/vlc/download-ubuntu.html) from the official Video-LAN site. Hope I helped :)

Comment: Thank you, but 2.03 is the latest version of vlc for precise (12.04). I've tried vlc 2.04 in LinuxMint on virtualbox with same negative results.

Comment: I see. I thought that 2.04 was latest, according to the front page (though I'm in Windows, so it could be incorrect as you said). It's definitely unusual, and I'm afraid I won't be of much used. I hope your question is solved quickly :)

Answer (score 0):

Could you try using avconv instead? AFAIK, they share a lot of the same encoders, so this will test if the problem is a mencoder-specific issue. To copy all streams, use:

```
avconv -i input.avi -c copy output.avi
```

(obviously use whatever file extensions are appropriate to your needs)

Comment: I've tried avconv and it works as expected.

Comment: avconv command line:  `avconv -i input.mkv -c:a ac3 -b 128k -c:v mpeg4 output.avi`  mencoder command line:  `mencoder input.mkv -oac lavc -ovc lavc -lavcopts vcodec=mpeg4:acodec=ac3:abitrate=128 -o output.avi -channels 5`  In both cases, the input file:  video -> h264  audio -> ac3 6 channels    If I use -oac copy with mencoder I get no sound, too.  The problem here is the mencoder+vlc combination, becasue the same encoded video with mencoder plays ok (with sound) in totem or mplayer.